# error: vagrant up on windows 7

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

**can someone help me in this please. i don't have any idea. im installing laravel homestead and i almost finish it. but my vagrant up command always show error. please help mo to fix this one. thank you!!**

```
ict@ict-PC MINGW32 ~/Homestead (master)
    $ vagrant up
    Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
    ==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
    ==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
        homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
        homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
    ==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
        homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
        homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    ==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    ==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
    ==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
        homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
        homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
        homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
        homestead-7:
        homestead-7: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
        homestead-7: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
        homestead-7:
        homestead-7: Inserting generated public key within guest...
        homestead-7: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
        homestead-7: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
    ==> homestead-7: Machine booted and ready!
    ==> homestead-7: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    ==> homestead-7: Setting hostname...
    ==> homestead-7: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
    ==> homestead-7: Mounting shared folders...
        homestead-7: /vagrant => C:/Users/ict/Homestead
    Vagrant was unable to mount VirtualBox shared folders. This is usually
    because the filesystem "vboxsf" is not available. This filesystem is
    made available via the VirtualBox Guest Additions and kernel module.
    Please verify that these guest additions are properly installed in the
    guest. This is not a bug in Vagrant and is usually caused by a faulty
    Vagrant box. For context, the command attempted was:

    mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vagrant /vagrant

    The error output from the command was:

    : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328775/virtualbox-mount-vboxsf-mounting-failed-with-the-error-no-such-device

Comment: Are you sure you are running the command in your intended directory ?